# get centroid latitude and longitude of h3 hexagon

Tags: python, h3

I know ho to get h3 hexagon ids for various resolutions and add them to a pandas dataframe containing latitudes and longitudes. Is it possible to get the centroid latitude and longitude of each h3 hexagon given its id? I saw function but do not know how to use it in this context cell_to_latlng. Any pointers would be very much appreciated. thanks.

PS:

```
import h3
dir(h3)
```

does not show cell_to_lat_lng btw?!

This does not work:

```
from h3 import h3

h3.cell_to_lat_lng('88396c0331fffff')
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'h3.api.basic_str' has no attribute 'cell_to_lat_lng'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently a discrepancy between the docs and the released version of the `h3-py` library - the docs are for v4, but the released version is still v3 (v4 is in beta). In H3v3, the function you want is called `h3_to_geo(hex_id)`.